# Fitting Sersic profile on data points with error bars in python

Tags: python, numpy, data-fitting

I have a set of data which I like to fit a 1D-Sersic profile (a function already defined in astropy) I can easily fit the data if I simply consider the data points without any error bars as below:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
from astropy.modeling.models import Sersic1D
##
data_LARS02 =np.loadtxt('/Users/a/data.asc')
##
r_l02        =  data[:,0]
flux_l02     =  data[:,1]   
###########################################Fitting 


sers_l02_init = Sersic1D(amplitude=5e40, r_eff=1, n=2)
fit_sers_l02 = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
Sers_l02 = fit_sers_l02(sers_l02_init,r_l02,flux_l02)
#####
```

The code works and everything is fine. However, I noticed there is a problem with the fit due to neglecting the error bars. Thus, I decided to include the error bars. But I do not know how to implement it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the [source code](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/_modules/astropy/modeling/fitting.html#LevMarLSQFitter) you have  a keyword `weights`. Did you try that?

Comment: I used the weights, but it was not contributing to the resulting fit ....

Comment: I am not familiar with the packages you are using, but I'll try to have a look. Can you post the try with weights? And maybe provide a minal data set to reproduce your results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting

####### Reading data #######
data_LARS02 =np.loadtxt('/Users/a/data.asc')

r_l02        =  data[:,0]
flux_l02     =  data[:,1]   
flux_err_l02 =  data[:,2] #assuming your data has errors at this column

####### Initiate the model and fitter #######
sers_l02_init = models.Sersic1D(amplitude=5e40, r_eff=1, n=2)
fit_sers_l02 = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter(calc_uncertainties=True)

####### Fitting the data #######
Sers_l02 = fit_sers_l02(sers_l02_init,r_l02,flux_l02,weights=1/(flux_err_l02**2))

####### Plotting the result #######
plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(r_l02, flux_l02, yerr=flux_err_l02, fmt='ko', label='Data')
plt.plot(r_l02, sers_l02_init(r_l02), 'b-', label='Initial Model')
plt.plot(r_l02, Sers_l02(r_l02), 'k-', label='Fitted Model')
plt.xlabel('Radius')
plt.ylabel('Flux')
plt.legend()
```

For more details, you can refer to their website: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/example-fitting-line.html#fit-using-uncertainties